# Can I get Nahkriin's mask if I've already left Skuldafn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've finshed the game skyrim but found out recently of the dragon priest masks and what to do with them. I have almost all of them but one I'm missing is the Nahkriin mask. Is there anyway that i can still somehow get it still? please help.

Comment: Do you have any save when you're in Skuldafn?

Answer (score 3):

*Nahkriin* is found in *Skuldafn*, therefore if you have completed *The World-Eater's Eyrie* from the main storyline then **you will not be able to acquire the mask without console commands**.

If you are on PC, you can use the following console command to add it:

```
player.additem 00061CA5 1
```

However if you are playing on consoles then you are unfortunately out of luck for this play through unless you have a save before completing the main story line.

Comment: Oh well that is a shame. Thankyou for the feedback.

Comment: @smitty69 No problem, if this has answered your question then you can mark it as such using the green tick box to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the XBox One there is another possibility:  The Mod ["The Cheat Room"](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3010376).

This provides, amongst other things, access to every item in the game.  It is, essentially, the back-door mechanism for "using the console" when you can't use the console.

There is, for the PS4, a similar but different mod provided by TheRealElianora (who provides the House Creation Club entries).  It provides access to the original test cell which already has "all the items.  This one is not as powerful as the XBox version, but it would provide this item.  The mod is called ["PS4 Cheat Mod"](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2986228).  There is also an XBox One version of this [mod](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2986181).

Answer (score 0):

There is one way if you go back to the save (if you have) at any point in the game and it will save after you have killed the priest but quickly go back to where you where originally (you have to save before you go back to the mission then once you have got the mask go back to the save you did were you where at at any point in the game) then if it works (its kind of a glitch) you will then have completed the task and should have that mask. Hope this helped